# Rails 3 - translating of routes with I18n

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want simple thing. Translate routes with I18n like this

```
get I18n.t('routes.login') => "devise/sessions#new", :as => :new_user_session
```

I made file initilizers/locale.rb with

```
I18n.default_locale = :cz
```

It works perfectly when i run 'rake routes', but when i run server it ignore default locale and throw 'translation missing message'

Any suggestion what is happening and why ?

Answer (score 2):

I believe, that normally routes are loaded once, even before locale are set, so you simply can't use the logic you have here. You need more advanced stuff to get it to work. Take a look at i18n_routing: http://github.com/kwi/i18n_routing

Comment: gem is a good suggestion for rails 2 and 3.  It apparently handles all urls shown in each locale you handle.  It does not touch in any way the database, so if you query in SQL you maintain the table name.